# Xamarin Forms string [] array binding to listview load fields but show empty TextCells

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use xamarin (NOTE: next month i going to migrate MAUI) the problem is when i get a json response from post request with many fields like  string fields and strings[] array, all the string fields show OK, but in listview show loads fields "empty", other words  string [] array binding to listview load fields but show empty TextCells if array have 3 strings, show 3 empty fields, see the code:
XAML:

```
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialities, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell DetailColor="Black"
                                      TextColor="Black"
                                      Text="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

VIEW MODEL:

```
             private string[] _specialities;
    public string[] Specialities
 {
        get => _specialities;
        set => SetProperty(ref _specialities, value);
    }
```

---------------CONTINUE

```
            string resultadoRespuesta = await 
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var problemDetails = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbogadosAtlasApi> 
             (resultadoRespuesta);
                    Nombres = problemDetails.FirtsNameOriginal;
                    Apellidos = 
                     problemDetails.LastNameOriginal;
                    Celular = problemDetails.Celular;
                    Correo = problemDetails.Correo;
                    Cedula = problemDetails.Cedula;
                    Especialidad = problemDetails.speciality;
                    Ciudad = problemDetails.Ciudadperfil;
                    Plan = problemDetails.Plan;
                    Specialities = problemDetails.Specialities;
```

I

was playing with this code:
foreach (string item in Specialities) { for (int ctr = 0; ctr < item.Length; ctr++) { Especialidadcon = item; }
the result is Especialidadcon show OK with the right value

a part of the json response i get from the endpoint:

```
           "firstName": "Juan Sebastián ",
  "lastName": "Mario mena ",
"email": "jdsa@lsddsdex.ec",
"phone": "099434346840",
"city": "59cda262fe728437ce90ff81",
"isDelete": false,
```

ATTETION: jsonproperty is ok i bind from MODEL AbogadosAtlasApi

```
          [JsonProperty("specialities")]
           public string[] Specialities { get; set; }
```

---

```
    "specialities": [
    "5990d6ff3da48f4bd98c6914",
    "5990d7273da48f4bd98c6918",
    "5990d75a3da48f4bd98c691d",
    "5a0a6087257e970afc9a9e73",
    "5a0a60ac257e970afc9a9e76",
    "5a13ecaf64de49704797d727"
      ],
     "role": "5a0a60a3257e970afc9a9e75",
```

SOLUTION: FOR LISTVIEW

```
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialitiess, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="sys:String">
                            <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                               TextColor="#503026" />
                                   
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Have you verified that Specialities actually contains the data that you think it does?  I don’t see anything obviously wrong with your code, so the first thing I would check is the data

Comment: Data is coming, example in app production, if response have 4 strings in specialities[] array... when i load the info the list view load 4 fields textcells can i select.. is like the info is load but the color of text and backgrond is white and create that effects that the textcelss are empty.... other fields LOAD OK.... after many research i stuck here

Comment: Try hardcoding a value for Text instead of binding it.  This will tell you if the problem is in the binding or the cell layout

Comment: `is like the info is load but the color of text and backgrond is white and create that effects that the textcelss are empty.... other fields LOAD OK`  I just find that there is only one string field for list `Specialities`. You can debug to see what the specific data is and whether it contains other fields?

Comment: making hardcoding, i get the value of item and set to Especialidadcon, and the value shows, i say the value SHOW OK (Especialidadcon) like unique string value of thah array... but how i get all the values?, back to the same an array  I add this code:                                                                                                  foreach (string item in Specialities)
                        {
                            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < item.Length; ctr++) {

                                Especialidadcon = item;
                            }

Comment: After many research i found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialitiess, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="sys:String">
                        <ViewCell>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                           HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                           TextColor="#503026" />
                               
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).